Getting error when trying to import keras-ocr
I tried to follow a tutorial about keras_ocr and straight from the beggining I get this problem that I cannot find any information on.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

plt.style.use('ggplot')

import keras_ocr

pipeline = keras_ocr.pipeline.Pipeline()
Looking for C:\Users\{myusername}\.keras-ocr\craft_mlt_25k.h5

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[65], line 3
      1 import keras_ocr
----> 3 pipeline = keras_ocr.pipeline.Pipeline()

File c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras_ocr\pipeline.py:22, in Pipeline.__init__(self, detector, recognizer, scale, max_size)
     20     detector = detection.Detector()
     21 if recognizer is None:
---> 22     recognizer = recognition.Recognizer()
     23 self.scale = scale
     24 self.detector = detector

File c:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras_ocr\recognition.py:388, in Recognizer.__init__(self, alphabet, weights, build_params)
    381 self.alphabet = alphabet
    382 self.blank_label_idx = len(alphabet)
    383 (
    384     self.backbone,
    385     self.model,
    386     self.training_model,
    387     self.prediction_model,
--> 388 ) = build_model(alphabet=alphabet, **build_params)
    389 if weights is not None:
    390     weights_dict = PRETRAINED_WEIGHTS[weights]
...
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32), array([1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.], dtype=float32)]}
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...

I tried installing and uninstalling keras using Anaconda Navigator Environments and tried installing and uninstalling keras-ocr using pip in a virtual environment in the project itself and also in a normal environment. Tried changing versions of Python, tensorflow and keras and absolutely nothing worked. I have also tried keras-orc without having tensorflow but still no luck.

Had the exact same issue, try with a lower version of Python.
Python 3.8.10 seems to work.

Try to change the tensorflow version, I have used pip install tensorflow==2.15 to fix this issue on my server.
